# Is there a method to auto flush when data changes in h5py?

Tags: python, h5py, flush

In h5py, the file in disk is not change when create group or dataset unless call file.flush(), how to implement auto flush when data changes?

I can wrap the h5py.File, but it does not work for subgroup.

```py
class MyH5py(h5py.File):
    def __init__(self, name, mode='r'):
        super(MyH5py, self).__init__(name, mode)

    def __setitem__(self, key, obj):
        super(MyH5py, self).__setitem__(key, obj)
        super(MyH5py, self).flush()

    def create_group(self, name, track_order=None):
        res = super(MyH5py, self).create_group(name, track_order)
        super(MyH5py, self).flush()
        return res

    def create_dataset(self, name, shape=None, dtype=None, data=None, **kwds):
        res = super(MyH5py, self).create_dataset(name, shape=None, dtype=None, data=None, **kwds)
        super(MyH5py, self).flush()
        return res
```

Does anyone have a similar problem and how to solve it? thanks.

Edit:

Add example:

```py
fh = MyH5py('f.h5', 'a')
group = fh.create_group('group')
group['dataset'] = 1 # not work
# group['dataset'].file.flush() # work

import time
time.sleep(300)
```

Run the code, then kill the python process when it was sleeping, it can seen that the 'group' is in the 'f.h5' but the 'dataset' is not exist.
The reason is that i can only add flush() to the root group in class MyH5py.

Comment: There isn't an auto-flush option. (HDF5 and h5py data is buffered.) To flush the buffer from RAM to disk you either have to flush or close the file. Is there a reason you need them to flush immediately?

Comment: I could not replicate your problem with `File.flush()`and group create (using your code).  I added `sleep(20)` so the program waited and the file wasn't closed automatically. I can see the group in HDF View. The issue may be at the OS level. From the HDF5 docs: "_HDF5 does not possess full control over buffering. H5Fflush flushes the internal HDF5 buffers then asks the operating system to flush the system buffers for the open files. After that, the OS is responsible for ensuring that the data is actually flushed to disk._"

Comment: @kcw78 I can not get the data if the program crashed before closing file,  this is not good for debugging when there are a lot of data operation of h5 object.

Comment: Use `with/as` context manager and that won't happen if your program exits unexpectedly. I will post an example as an answer. Behavior when you kill the program is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have a file `close()` method at the end of your program. When you exit cleanly you get lucky and Python does this for you. It's good practice to close files that you opened.

It's better to use Python's `with/as` context manager to open the file. If/when you exit abnormally (either due to a program crash or the file isn't closed because of coding errors) it  will run the appropriate tear down processes (e.g., close the file).

**Don't do this:**

```
fh = h5py.File('f.h5', 'a')
group = fh.create_group('group')
dlist = [i for i in range(10)]
ds = group.create_dataset('test',data=dlist)
ds.flush() 
fh.close()
```

**Instead, do this:**

```
with h5py.File('f.h5', 'a') as fh:
    group = fh.create_group('group')
    dlist = [i for i in range(10)]
    ds = group.create_dataset('test',data=dlist)
    ### ds.flush() ### NOT NEEDED
    ### fh.close() ### NOT NEEDED
```

Killing a process externally (from the OS) is an extreme event (like a system crash or power failure). When that happens I suspect the context manager will not be able to execute tear down process. Why are you doing that?

EDIT: To see if the data was flushed, I added a `sleep(15)` line to my program, and was able to open and view the H5 file with HDFView while the program was paused. The group was created and flushed. (I also created some attributes and could see them.) So, the `flush()` operation is working. However, that's not a guarantee it will work on a system crash. Your problem may be due to an error when you kill the process and the file can't close properly.

As an aside, creating a custom class to manage all HDF5/h5py file process may become a headache (for you). You will have to replicate other the h5py methods. For example, it looks like your `__setitem__()` method is supposed to create attributes (based on `key, obj` parameters). If so, it doesn't. It creates datasets where the name is `key` and the data is `obj`. Instead you need to use the `.attrs()` method.

Comment: Thanks! The reason i kill the process is that processes using excessive memory on servers will be killed by OS and it is helpful to be able to see the h5 data if this happens.